# Scipy/numpy: two dense, one sparse dot product

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, scipy

Let's say we have a matrix `A` of size `NxN`, and `A` is sparse and `N` is very large. So we naturally want to store is as as scipy sparse matrix.

We also have a dense numpy array `q` of size `NxK`, where `K` is relatively smaller.

How do we most efficiently perform `q.T * A * q`, where `*` is matrix multiplication, to obtain a `KxK` result?

One part of what we want can be done efficiently, that is just `A * q`, but once you do that you materialize a dense array that you then need to multiply with another dense array.

Any way to do it faster than `q.T.dot(A.dot(q))`?

Answer (score 0):

So you have

```
(k,N) * (N,N) * (N,k) => (k,k)
```

One of those dot product results in a dense array; that times another dense is also dense.  With a multiplication like this you quickly loose the sparsity.

If `q` has a lot of 0s, and you want to preserve the sparse matrix nature of the problem, make `q` sparse before doing this multiplication.